# Find array element based on it's value (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
[
 0 [product_id, title, description]
 1 [1234, apple, this is just apple]
 2 [2345, pineapple, this is not just apple]
]
```

This array is long and product_id's can vary by a lot.
I need to select an element based on it's `product_id` and update it's `title` and `description`.

Is there a way to do it without a `for` loop (such as `for -> if product_id = id -> do something`), since I will end up with n^2?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Nope, not really, if you want the outer array based on it's content you have to iterate

Comment: Why not have a collection instead? `[{id: 1, title: 'Foo', description: 'baz'}, ...]`

Comment: Single scan of an array is O(n).

Comment: and how would I call a member of a collection without parsing through all the elements?

Comment: PM 77-1, but I always have an array of changes, so it is parsing 2 arrays

Comment: You wouldn't neccessarely have to parse through all of them, you can stop when you've found what you're looking for, unless there are duplicate ID's

Comment: Your approach isn't very object-oriented. Why would you have the first index of an array be an array of property names? Your array should look more like @elclanrs comment. Though, this won't directly solve your problem it's much easier to maintain.

Comment: Why would you end up with n^2?

Comment: Jeez -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/trm1x8km/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assumption: product_id is unique

For an array there is no other way but to loop through it all.  You should consider changing your datamodel into a JSON then it will become much easier.

In your example

```
var products = [
 0 [product_id, title, description]
 1 [1234, apple, this is just apple]
 2 [2345, pineapple, this is not just apple]
]
```

becomes

```
var products = {
    product_id: [product_id, title, description],
    1234: [1234, apple, this is just apple],
    2345: [2345, pineapple, this is not just apple]
}
```

Now you can simply say

```
var select_1234 = products[1234];
```

to get the product of 1234.

If you must stick with the array and you need to find products multiple times, consider doing a transform at the beginning of your app to change it into json.  As such you have indexed your data and now you can again call

```
products[1234]
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can create json data to link to your array for example

```
var productsIndex = {
    product_id: 0,
    1234: 1,
    2345: 2
}
```

This links to the position of the array so now you can call

```
var find = productsIndex[1234];
var select_1234 = products[find]; //This is the original array.
```

As an extra, consider using async transformations to transform the data so it does not freeze up any UI.
This can be done using a recursive setTimeout with 0 seconds

```
var products = {
    product_id: [product_id, title, description],
    1234: [1234, apple, this is just apple],
    2345: [2345, pineapple, this is not just apple]
}

var productsIndex = {}

function recursiveTransform(val){
    setTimeout(function(){
        productsIndex[products[val].[0]] = val; //products[val].[0] is the product id of each array element
        if (val != products.length -1) recursiveTransform(val+1);
    }, 0)
}

recursiveTransform(0);
```

By doing this, you will not freeze up your ui or any other operation that might need to be run during the process

- I haven't tested the code but it should give you an idea

Comment: I can't use product_id as id, but thanks for the advice about transforming it to JSON - that might actually work

Comment: JSON is a dataformat for strings, I don't see how that helps, but maybe it's just me ?

Comment: @adeneo JSON is a key value data structure.

Comment: That would be a javascript object !

Comment: @user3078775 can you not use this method because product_id is not unique?

Comment: @DylanWatt You're right dylan, this method will not work if the product_id is not unique which is my assumption since it's an 'identifier'

Comment: @YangLi in your edit, why make the productsIndex values the index key instead of the actual product array? Since it's pass by reference, you can update one and it will affect both data structures. In your method, if the array is transformed in anyway, you have to regenerate your map.

Comment: @DylanWatt Correct again, but this one is more of a semantic reason more than anything.  It's just easier to track this way and easier to debug imo.  Also, you may want to know the location of the array object and send back to the server information of the location.

Comment: @YangLi fair enough, it's 6 of one. I like the pass by reference method in angular just for situations like `ng-if="product === lookupMap['somekey']"`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to lookup like you want. You'll need to create a map. That map can either replace your initial array in your data, if it makes sense, or you can just generate a lookup map that you refer to later.

Luckily if you set `fooarray[0] = bar;foomap['uuid'] = bar;`, you can update bar via either data structure eg `fooarray[0][1] = 'new title'` or `foomap['uuid'][1] = 'new title'` and it will update in both structures, because it's passed by reference.

edit building on @YangLi:

```
var products = {
    product_id: [product_id, title, description],
    1234: [1234, apple, this is just apple],
    2345: [2345, pineapple, this is not just apple]
}

var productsIndex = {}

function recursiveTransform(val){
    setTimeout(function(){
        productsIndex[products[val].[0]] = products[val];
        if (val != products.length -1) recursiveTransform(val+1);
    }, 0)
}

recursiveTransform(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
[
  [2439, 'title', 'description'],
  [1234, 'apple', 'this is just apple'],
  [2345, 'pineapple', 'this is not just apple']
].findIndex(function(a){return a[0] == 1234}); // returns 1
```

```
[
  [2439, 'title', 'description'],
  [1234, 'apple', 'this is just apple'],
  [2345, 'pineapple', 'this is not just apple']
].find(function(a){return a[0] == 1234}); // returns [1234, 'apple', 'this is just apple']
```

I’d recommend to simply use a polyfill as well. See the links: they offer polyfills for both so that Chrome and IE can support this as well.

Comment: Arrow functions can't be polyfilled.

Comment: You can use normal functions as well, I’ve edited the answer so that normal functions are used.

Comment: The polyfill is still a scan, though. If the concern is performance today, it's not the way to go. It'll be nice when ES6 starts to come online for real though.

Comment: @DylanWatt The two methods internally are scans as well so it doesn’t make a huge difference.

Comment: @Xufox, I would assume the "native code" scan should be more performant? If not, then it comes back to the fact the original question was how to avoid scanning.

Comment: @DylanWatt I think avoiding scanning is kinda impossible, isn’t it (if the product IDs are in unpredictable order, that is…)?

Comment: @Xufox A scan is needed, but if you generate a lookup map, you only need to scan once. In your solution, it has to scan every time.